# Create a byte array barcode using B4j

Tags: java, rest, barcode, barcode4j

```
@Override
    public String generateBrcodeForId(String Id) {
        BarcodeUtil util = BarcodeUtil.getInstance();
        BarcodeGenerator gen;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;
        try {
            gen = util.createBarcodeGenerator(buildCfg("code128"));
        OutputStream fout;
            fout = new FileOutputStream("code128.jpg");
              byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int resolution = 200;
        BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(
                fout, "image/jpeg", resolution, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, false, 0);
        gen.generateBarcode(canvas, "12345678");
            canvas.finish();
        } catch (ConfigurationException | BarcodeException | IOException  e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


     private static Configuration buildCfg(String type) {
            DefaultConfiguration cfg = new DefaultConfiguration("barcode");

            //Bar code type
            DefaultConfiguration child = new DefaultConfiguration(type);
              cfg.addChild(child);

              //Human readable text position
              DefaultConfiguration attr = new DefaultConfiguration("human-readable");
              DefaultConfiguration subAttr = new DefaultConfiguration("placement");
                subAttr.setValue("bottom");
                attr.addChild(subAttr);

                child.addChild(attr);
            return cfg;
          }
```

Have created a bar code using Barcode4j, Here its creating a image code128.jpg. Can I create a byte array instead Of creating an image in the filesystem and send that to the web service client.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, solved it using ByteArrayOutputStream

```
@Override
    public byte[] generateBarcodeForId(String Id) {
        BarcodeUtil util = BarcodeUtil.getInstance();
        BarcodeGenerator gen;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = null;
        try {
            gen = util.createBarcodeGenerator(buildCfg("code128"));
        OutputStream fout;
        int resolution = 100;
        bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(
                bao, "image/jpeg", resolution, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, false, 0);
        gen.generateBarcode(canvas, Id);
        canvas.finish();

        } catch (ConfigurationException | BarcodeException | IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {  
            try {
                bao.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }  


        return bao.toByteArray();
    }

     private static Configuration buildCfg(String type) {
            DefaultConfiguration cfg = new DefaultConfiguration("barcode");

            //Bar code type
            DefaultConfiguration child = new DefaultConfiguration(type);
              cfg.addChild(child);

              //Human readable text position
              DefaultConfiguration attr = new DefaultConfiguration("human-readable");
              DefaultConfiguration subAttr = new DefaultConfiguration("placement");
                subAttr.setValue("bottom");
                attr.addChild(subAttr);

                child.addChild(attr);
            return cfg;
          }
```